# Не могу прервать выполнение Phantomjs в Java

Tags: java, swing, gui, phantomjs

У меня есть интерфейс в котором есть кнопка старт, она запускает Phantomjs,
но в момент запуска, интерфейс становиться недоступным, до тех пор пока полностью не выполниться Phantomjs, т-е я нажимаю на кнопку "закрыть" и программа не закрывается. 
Как сделать чтобы интерфейс не замораживался в момент запуска phantomjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно запустить выполнение вашего `phantomjs` процесса в другом потоке:

Создаем класс для потока:

```
public class PhantomJS implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // phantomjs code
    }

}
```

В нужно месте запускаем:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PhantomJS());
```

Класс изменяйте как вам нужно. Весь рабочий код содержится в методе `run`.

Comment: Я выполняю SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PhantomJS()); по нажатию на кнопку старт, но интерфейс по-прежнему недоступен.

Comment: Вот ивент нажатия: public class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
         try {
          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PhantomJS());
    
   } catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
   }
        }
    }

Comment: Вот код PhantomJS:              public class PhantomJS implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     String phantomjsExeutableFilePath = "phantomjs.exe";
  System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", phantomjsExeutableFilePath);
   WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(); 
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login");
   try {
   Thread.sleep(2000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
   System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    }
}

Comment: @Shelmn попробуйте запустить поток через `SwingWorker`. Если же нет то запускайте обычным `new Thread`.

Comment: Через SwingWorker работает, огромное спасибо